# Remove all elements from array that match specific string

Tags: javascript

What is the easiest way to remove all elements from array that match specific string? For example:

`array = [1,2,'deleted',4,5,'deleted',6,7];`

I want to remove all `'deleted'` from the array.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Simply use the **[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** function for obtain elements of a condition

```
var array = [1,2,'deleted',4,5,'deleted',6,7];
var newarr = array.filter(function(a){return a !== 'deleted'})
```

### Update: ES6 Syntax

```
let array = [1,2,'deleted',4,5,'deleted',6,7]
let newarr = array.filter(a => a !== 'deleted')
```

Comment: It's even nicer with arrow syntax. `array.filter(a => a !== 'deleted');`

Comment: How would you modify this if you wanted to delete elements that contains part of your search term? `take this array [1, 2, 'delete', 4, 5, 'deleted', 6, 'will delete']`. What if one wanted to remove any element that matches even part of the string 'del'? So 'delete', 'deleted' and 'will delete' are all removed?

Comment: @user1837608 at that point you'd be safer dealing with Regex Matching than standard matching, or match on n elements of the string, but that would be an expensive operation for no real benefit at that point, since it would clutter itself with 'will delete', if needed I can place an answer for this below, but doesn't directly match the question I believe.

Answer (score 11):

If you have multiple strings to remove from main array, You can try this

```
// Your main array 
var arr = [ '8','abc','b','c'];

// This array contains strings that needs to be removed from main array
var removeStr = [ 'abc' , '8'];

arr = arr.filter(function(val){
  return (removeStr.indexOf(val) == -1 ? true : false)
})

console.log(arr);

// 'arr' Outputs to :
[ 'b', 'c' ]
```

OR

**Better Performance(Using hash)** , If strict type equality not required

```
// Your main array 
var arr = [ '8','deleted','b','c'];

// This array contains strings that needs to be removed from main array
var removeStr = [ 'deleted' , '8'];
var removeObj = {};  // Use of hash will boost performance for larger arrays
removeStr.forEach( e => removeObj[e] = true);

var res = arr.filter(function(val){
  return !removeObj[val]
})

console.log(res);

// 'arr' Outputs to :
[ 'b', 'c' ]
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want the same array then you can use

```
var array = [1,2,'deleted',4,5,'deleted',6,7];
var index = "deleted";
for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(array[i] === index) {
       array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

[EXAMPLE 1](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yot75gpg/)

else you can use `Array.prototype.filter` which creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
 var arrayVal = [1,2,'deleted',4,5,'deleted',6,7];
function filterVal(value) {
  return value !== 'deleted';
}
var filtered = arrayVal.filter(filterVal);
```

[EXAMPLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yot75gpg/1/)

Comment: I needed to keep the same array, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
array = array.filter(function(s) {
    return s !== 'deleted';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A canonical answer would probably look like this:

```js
[10, 'deleted', 20, 'deleted'].filter(x => x !== 'deleted');
//=> [10, 20]
```

There's nothing unexpected here; any developers can read, understand and maintain this code. From that perspective this solution is great. I just want to offer some different perspectives.

Firstly I sometimes struggle with the semantic of filter when the condition is "reversed":

```js
[2, 3, 2, 3].filter(x => x === 2);
[2, 3, 2, 3].filter(x => x !== 2);
```

This is a contrived example but I bet a few readers did pause for a nanosecond. These small cognitive bumps can be exhausting in the long run.

I personally wish there would be a reject method:

```js
[2, 3, 2, 3].filter(x => x === 2);
[2, 3, 2, 3].reject(x => x === 2);
```

Secondly there's a lot of "machinery" in this expression `x => x === 2`: a function expression, a parameter and an equality check.

This could be abstracted away by using a curried function:

```js
const eq =
  x => y =>
    x === y;

[2, 3, 2, 3].filter(eq(2));
//=> [2, 2]
```

We can see that `eq(2)` is the same as `x => x === 2` just shorter and with added semantic.

Now let's build a `reject` function and use `eq`:

```js
const reject =
  (pred, xs) =>
    xs.filter(x =>
      pred(x) === false);

reject(eq(2), [2, 3, 2, 3]);
//=> [3, 3]
```

But what if we need to reject other things? Well we can build an `either` function that uses `eq`:

```js
const either =
  (...xs) => y =>
    xs.some(eq(y));

reject(either(1, 2), [1, 3, 2, 3]);
//=> [3, 3]
```

Finally to answer your question:

```js
reject(eq('deleted'), [1, 'deleted', 3]);
//=> [1, 3]

reject(either('deleted', 'removed'), [1, 'deleted', 3, 'removed', 5]);
//=> [1, 3, 5]
```

We could go further and remove based on different predicates *e.g. remove if matches the string "delete" or is 0*.

Let's build a `eitherfn` function that takes a list of predicates:

```js
const eitherfn =
  (...fn) => y =>
    fn.some(f =>
      f(y));
```

And now let's build a `match` function:

```js
const match =
  x => y =>
    typeof y === 'string'
      ? y.includes(x)
      : false;
```

Then:

```js
reject(eitherfn(match('delete'), eq(0)), [0, 1, 'deleted', 3, 'will delete', 5])
// [1, 3, 5]
```