# Remove all matching elements from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```js
["onelolone", "twololtwo", "three"]
```

How can I remove the elements using only `'lol'` as value and as result be:

```js
["three"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all elements from array that match specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249774/remove-all-elements-from-array-that-match-specific-string)

Comment: You wanna remove the items that don't contain "lol"?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and check that it doesn't include `"lol"`:

```js
const result = ["onelolone","twololtwo","three"].filter(ele => !ele.includes("lol"))

console.log(result)// ["three"]
```

Comment: Nice exactly what I been looking for. I have a question, if I want to include more values like ("lol","th") and expect = console.log(result)// [ ]. How can that be achieved?

Comment: `.filter(ele => !["lol", "th"].some(phrase => ele.includes(phrase))`

Answer (score 0):

`Array#filter` is used to *keep* elements that satisfy a predicate. But we can build a `reject` function that *removes* the elements that satisfy a predicate:

```js
const reject = fn => xs => xs.filter(x => fn(x) === false);
```

Then we can build a curried function for matching a string:

```js
const matches = x => y => y.includes(x);
```

```js
const reject_lol = reject(matches("lol"));

reject_lol(["onelolone", "twololtwo", "three"]);
//=> ["three"]
```

We can tweak `matches` to support any number of strings:

```js
const matches = (...xs) => y => xs.some(x => y.includes(x));
```

```js
const reject_abbr = reject(matches("lol", "wtf"));

reject_abbr(["lolone", "twowtf", "three"]);
//=> ["three"]
```