# Remove all elements in an array that contain a certain character

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have a Javascript array `var array = ["1-2", "3-6", "4", "1-6", "4"]` and want to remove all elements that contain the variable `var m = "6"`, i.e. "3-6" and "1-6".

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249774/remove-all-elements-from-array-that-match-specific-string) this line of code `var newarray = array.filter(a => a !== "4")`, which creates a new array that does not contain the two "4" elements. But I have not found out how to use regular expressions in order to remove all elements that CONTAIN the given variable `m = "6"`.

I thought about something like `var newarray = array.filter(a => a !== /eval("return m")/)`, but this does not work.

I very appreciate your help and apologize for my English :)

Comment: what you want is `/6/g.test(a)`

Comment: That's not a use-case for regular expression. You don't have a pattern. You have a static string. You want [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes): `const newarray = array.filter(a => !a.includes('6'));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### string.includes()

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

```js
const array = ["1-2", "3-6", "4", "1-6", "4"];

const newarray = array.filter(a => !a.includes("6"))

console.log(newarray);
```

### regex alternative

if you need complex pattern checking, the regex is the way to go.

```js
const array = ["1-2", "3-6", "4", "1-6", "4"];

const newarray = array.filter(a => !a.match(/6/gi))

console.log(newarray);
```

> For example, checking uppercase and lowercase simultaneously, or multiple letters only with `[abcde]` or some numbers `[678]` etc...
>
> without nested `includes()` or logic with if/else.

for learning regex you can use this https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/#regular-expressions

another info:

> with regex I suggest to add also the `g` at the end just in case `/6/g`
>
> `g` means global (but in this case isn't important, because if there are 6 at least one time. this code will work fine (if you care about multiple 6 then use `g`)

> also use `i` if you want to select also texts
>
> in fact without `i`: "A" and "a" aren't the same
>
>  so with `i` you don't have to worry about UPPERCASE or lowercase
>
> you can use both them by doing like this `/6/gi`

Comment: "TypeError: a.contain is not a function"

Comment: @andy was a grammarly wrong correction, when typing is changed automatically the text. sorry changed/corrected